# Proper jquery selector choices

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this part of my form:

```
<input name="myName" type="text" value="myValue">
```

My questions are:

- what's the proper selector to get the value based on the name?
- how to get the "name" only, based on that input stuff just without adding any #id nor class attributes.

Comment: @sasori What do you mean by 'how to get the "name" only, based from that input stuff alone without adding any #id nor class attributes'? Are you trying to get a list of names for input tags on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like:

```
$('input[name="name-of-input"]')
```

And then you can extract the value using:

```
var v = $('input[name="name-of-input"]').val();
```

If you want to get a list of names of input elements on your page then you'll need to add a bit more, e.g. to enumerate the tags and output their names:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function (idx, elem) { 
    alert($(elem).attr('name')); 
});
```

You could make this more specific by adding a `class` attribute to the inputs you want to examine (in it's current form the code above will look at ALL textboxes on the page).

Comment: not sure if `$('input[name="name-of-input"]')` will do, because I'm using php variable for the name and value

Comment: @sasori I've updated my answer to include some code that lets you get a list of names for input elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector by attribute:

```
$('input[name="myname"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like so: `$('input[name="name"]')`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use attribute selection.

e.g.

```
$('input[name="NameYouAreLookingFor"]');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
$('input[name="input_name_here"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option...

```
var value = $("[name=''.$id.'']").attr("value");
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FKW2H/1/)

To work with external JS file...

in JS file:

```
var knownID;

function SetID(id){
   knownID = id;
}

function UsingValue(){
   var value = $("[name='" + knownID + "']").attr("value");
}
```

in PHP page (javascript function on page load):

```
SetID(.$id.); //not sure the correct syntax for PHP rendering
```

Though I would just prefer to do my JavaScript on the PHP page, if I need some heavy functions I would pass the element to the JS file to be used

Comment: but am using an external js file and it's the name and value are using php variables, is this legal ?

Comment: @sasori: I don't think it will work with an external js file. How would you expect the file to know what the $id value is meant to be? YOu could add an "Init()" sort of function to your js file and pass it the id from your page.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is a bit odd. Are you also using php as well? Why the dots, inverted commas, and the dollar sign as your id and value?

In any event

```
<input id="id" name="id" type="text" value="textvalue">
```

you should use the  `.val()` function.

```
$('#id').val();
```

Comment: That selector is incorrect. It uses the ID attribute which is not specified on the tag.

Answer (score 0):

If @mdm is correct (and I think he is) your question is not sufficiently detailed to give the full answer.

If there is some event triggered such as an `onfocus` which you want to trigger an action than you could conceivably use the `this.id` selector to dynamically get your element's ID but because you have not posted the full code it is not possble to show you how this would work.

Comment: situation is, it's a single page, where the contents are being loaded dynamicaly. each data has an input field as posted above, and there's only one single button. to push, in order to update the qty of each data via ajax call .. am using an <input type="image" submit thing

Comment: @sasori this can be handled in at least three different ways, but you have not included the code that handles the interaction you mention in this comment. Are you trying to do something after the submit button is pressed? Are you trying to do something when a user clicks on the field? Are you trying to do something after the response from the server? Please add **a lot** more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple like CSS to read the textfield parameter. 

use the jquery command to get their values.. 
 here's my example :

$('object_parameter').val();

easier.